# Issue to install Geotrust certificate (SSL) on Tomcat

Tags: ssl, https, ssl-certificate

I got a certificate from Geotrust and I'm trying to apply it to my Tomcat web server, as can be seen in the image below, I left .csr and .p7b in the same directory (java / bin)

[image]

the softlayer support team, has indicated the link https://www.digicert.com/ssl-certificate-installation-tomcat.htm as help and when I execute the command I get the error:keytool error: **java.lang.Exception: Input not an X.509 certificate**

Anyone have been through this and can you help me? I've been trying to figure it out for days.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Reasons for the error :-

You are importing the certificate (p7b) in a wrong keystore . when you import the certificate in an existing keystore it will never ask you to punch in the password twice.  If its asking you to punch in the password twice, it means its creating a new keystore. In a new keystore, you cannot import the the certificates as private entry  You can only create Trusted Entry and add the certificates as trusted.

**Solution**

1)If you have the private key with you, please create a text file and rename the file as  example.pem  with all the certificates and private key in it  in the below sequence

```
a) private key

b) Server certificate

c) Intermediate Certificate

d) Root Certificate.
```

2) Run the below openssl command

openssl pkcs12 -in example.pem -out certificate.pfx

3) As you have the pfx file from the above command, use the keytool command below to convert this in jks format for tomcat

keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore certificate.pfx -srcstoretype
    pkcs12 -destkeystore certificate.jks -deststoretype jks.

4) Provide the certificate.jks directive in server.xml file of tomcat along with its password

5) Restart the tomcat service.

Hope this helps ..